# Exponent of adjacency matrix in a graph

Tags: graph-theory

Does the meaning of n-th exponent of adjacency matrix giving us number of walks from some node to other remain, if i have a self-loop, i.e. a node connected to itself?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, even there is loop in the graph, the $n$-exponent of the matrix just indicate the number of walk of length $n$ between vertices.